# Complex blog post layout with full width hero image and sidebar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve the following layout in Bootstrap 4.

[image: Complex layout]

Please note:

- `image`, `header` and `.entry-content` are within the `main` element
- `.sidebar` is within the `aside` element

I'm constrained by this layout (using Roots Sage).

The `image` and `header` should pop out of `main` and stretch to the full width of `article`.

I realize this probably isn't too complicated to achieve with some basic absolute positioning techniques.The complexity is introduced by the fact that `header` can be of variable height depending on the length of the text and that the vertical position of `aside` should adjust relative to this.

Would love some help with this. Thanks!

Comment: Not possible without script, or a markup change.

Comment: I could break the template and make a markup change. I wanted to see if there was any way to achieve this by conserving the semantics of the template. In my view the `header` and `image` should be part of the `article` tag.

Comment: Here is the fiddle from my deleted answer to start with, using your existing markup:  https://jsfiddle.net/43kow9q2/